# How to Consume Apis from Asp .Net Core using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, .net, asp.net-core

I have this Asp Net Core Web Api application as my backend with all the Apis that I need using default route system `localhost\api\controller\id`. All Apis are working fine when calling from PostMan, but when I try to use Jquery Ajax to call them in my FrontEnd, things don't run properly. Sorry if this question looks stupid, I'm new to JavaScript so ill really appreciate your guys help!

I only have got the 'Get' method to list in a table modifying the HTML with the result:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#btn-lista-alunos').click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url,
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json', // Returns JSON
            success: function (response) {
                $('#tabela-alunos td').remove("");
                $('#info p').remove();
                var sTxt = '';
                $.each(response, function (index, val) {
                    sTxt += '<tr>';
                    sTxt += '<td>' + val.id + '</td>';
                    sTxt += '<td>' + val.nome + '</td>';
                    sTxt += '<td>' + val.ra + '</td>';
                    sTxt += '<td>' + val.curso + '</td>';
                    sTxt += '<td>' + val.periodo + '</td>';
                    sTxt += '<td>' + val.nota + '</td>';
                    sTxt += '<td>' + ValidaStatus(val.nota) + '</td>';

                    sTxt += '</tr>';
                });
                $('#tabela-alunos').append(sTxt);
            },
            error: function () {
                $('#info').html('<p>Ocorreu um erro, verifique a conexão com a api!</p>');
            }
        });
    });
    //Botao Limpar Lista
    $('#btnClear').click(function () {
        $('#tabela-alunos td').remove();
        $('#info p').remove();
    });
});
```

My first Html Page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">

<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <script src="Scripts/app.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "Content/content.css" />
    <title>Banco Alunos</title>
</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <h1>
            <p>Banco de Alunos</p>
        </h1>
    </header>

    <section class="sessao_botoes">
        <h2>
            <input onclick="location.href = 'incluir.html' ;" " id="btn-incluir" type="button" value="Incluir"/>
            <input id="btn-editar" type="button" value="Editar" />
            <input id="btn-excluir" type="button" value="Excluir" />
            <input id="btn-lista-alunos" type="button" value="Listar Alunos" />
            <input onclick="location.href = '' ;" " id="btn-incluir" type="button" value="Filtrar Alunos"/>
            <input id="btnClear" type="button" value="Limpar Listagem" />
        </h2>
    </section>

    <p><br /><br /></p>
    <section>
        <h3>
            <table id="tabela-alunos">
                <tr>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>Nome</th>
                    <th>RA</th>
                    <th>Curso</th>
                    <th>Periodo</th>
                    <th>Nota</th>
                    <th>Status</th>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <div id="updatemessage"></div>
            <p id="info"></p>
        </h3>
    </section>

</body>

</html>
```

My Second HTML Page with the Post Form:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/app.js"></script>
    <title>Incluir Aluno</title>
</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <h1>
            <p>Incluir Novo Aluno</p>
        </h1>
    </header>
    <section>
        <h2>
            <form id="myForm" action="http://localhost:51700/api/Alunos" method="post">
                <p>
                    <label>Nome: </label>
                    <input type="text" name="nome">
                </p>
                <p>
                    <label>RA: </label>
                    <input type="number" maxlength="8" name="ra">
                </p>
                <p>
                    <label>Periodo: </label>
                    <input type="text" name="periodo">
                </p>
                <p>
                    <label>Curso: </label>
                    <input type="text" name="curso">
                </p>
                <p>
                    <label>Nota: </label>
                    <input type="number" max="10" maxlength="4" name="nota">
                </p>
                <p>
                    <input id="btnCadastro" type="submit" value="Cadastrar">
                </p>
            </form>
            <p>
                <input onclick="location.href = 'index.html'" type="submit" value="Voltar">
            </p>
        </h2>
    </section>
</body>

</html>
```

How can I use Ajax to send the form as a JSON to my BackEnd and Edit/Delete an Object Value Listed on my first page? I already have tried quite a few things but none of that worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here I am... 
I learned how to call most of them with ajax:
PS: in my web asp net core BackEnd I had to do alot of stufs related to CORS for allow me to call the APIs, follow the link for more details: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/web-api-javascript?view=aspnetcore-3.0

```
//Get
$.ajax({
   url: "url",
   type: 'GET',
   dataType: 'json',
   success: function (response) {
   //do something}
});


//Post
$.ajax({
   headers: {
   Accept': 'application/json',
             'Content-Type': 'application/json'
},
   type: 'POST',
   url: "url",
   data: JSON.stringify(cadastro),
   uccess: function (result) {
   $("#myForm")[0].reset();
   alert("Sucesso");
},
   error: function () {
   alert("error");
}
});


//DeleteOne
    $.ajax({
        url: "url/" + id,
        type: 'DELETE',
        success: function (result) {
            $(param).parents("tr").remove();
        }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The first thing is why you use HTML page instead of asp.net core cshtml pages ? The framework provided the pages have lots of the features like Model binding .

You can use jquery to get the values from your html page and then use Ajax to post data to server side :

```
var data = { 
    StartDate: "1/19/2016",
    EndDate: "4/19/2016",
    ProductType: "New",
    Count: 1
};

$.ajax({
url: '/Home/Edit',
type: 'POST',
data: JSON.stringify(data),
contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    success: function (data) {
        window.location.href = "";
}
});
```

In success function of ajax , you can use `window.location.href`  to redirect to another page as shown above .

On server side , you can use `FromBody` to get values from request body :

```
public IActionResult Edit([FromBody]MyViewModel myViewModel)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {

    }
    return Json("OK");
}

public class MyViewModel {

    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
    public string ProductType { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: It was intentional, I was instigated in how to make systems in different scenarios communicate data between them. it's all good now. Thx!